# How to bypass the .htaccess file in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use a crawling software to create my xml file to submit automatically to search engines, and a redirection command creates an issue with this software. I tried different solutions. None was working, so my latest idea was to ask the program to bypass the .htaccess file. I would like to know how to do it in php.

If it is not possible, this is the line that creates problem (because of the dash in the domain name).

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.art\-svp\.com\/m\/1" [R=301,L]
```

I tried it without the \ before the - : same issue.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.art-svp\.com\/m\/1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I doubt you can bypass an `.htaccess` file. If so, that'd mean a big security hole/breach.

Comment: You could however setup different rules to let certain sites do certain things.

Comment: Thank you, now ! know. I added in my top question the rules that creates the issue.

Comment: You could try an `Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from example.com` and run an `ErrorDocument 403 http://www.X-site.com` to deny. That's all I can think of.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I am going to research to find out how to do that